# Amazon Elastic MapReduce: Failed to create a job flow with a large number of instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce

Every time I attempt to create a job flow with more than 20 instances, the creation fails.
It works for me most of the time with less than 20 instances.

Is there any limitation on the number of instances allowed for a job flow?

By the way, I use ERM CLI:

```
ruby elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --key-pair key --num-instances 30 --name MyJobFlow
```

Then I see:

```
j-3KRJLHMHWR1ZC     FAILED      MyJobFlow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Amazon limits accounts to 20 instances. You can go to http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ec2-request/ to request more instances.

Comment: I wish the error message was more self descriptive. Thanks very much!